# Zipping folder with images return empty files

Tags: go

I am trying to zip a folder containing files using following code

```
func zipFolder(source string) error {
    target := "uniq.zip"
    zipfile, err := os.Create(target)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer zipfile.Close()
    archive := zip.NewWriter(zipfile)
    defer archive.Close()

    info, err := os.Stat(source)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }

    var baseDir string
    if info.IsDir() {
        baseDir = filepath.Base(source)
    }

    filepath.Walk(source, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        header, err := zip.FileInfoHeader(info)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if baseDir != "" {
            header.Name = filepath.Join(baseDir, strings.TrimPrefix(path, source))
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            header.Name += "/"
        } else {
            header.Method = zip.Store
        }
        writer, err := archive.CreateHeader(header)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }
        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()
        _, err = io.Copy(writer, file)
        return err
    })

    return err
}
```

This successfully generates a zip while but when i unzip it (I am using mac), the compressed file is of 0 bytes without any content.
Any idea what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't ignore the error returned by filepath.Walk.

Comment: If you passed a path to a single file as "source", then a new empty .zip archive will be created, then your program quits. See, in this case, your baseDir will be empty, thus filepath.Walk won't do anything, because there is no directory to traverse.